# How do I write a C# list query accross 3 tables in 2 different Azure SQL Databases

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, azure

I have a need to add code to feed into existing code a list of object names to go pull from an Azure Blob Store.  The gotcha is that the table I am pulling the list from is a Table of Blob Names in one SQL Azure DB (AdminDB)  And the actual list I need to construct is from an aggregate of 3 tables in another SQL Azure DB (runtimeDB)  so I cannot just do a JOIN query across the two since Azure's virtualized DBs don't allow that.

Furthermore for performance reasons the runtimeDB doesn't use BlobNames but instead uses an internalId that has to be looked up in an intermediary table in the runtimeDB

So I have the following C# definitions

```
 public partial class adminDb : DbContext
 {
     public virtual DbSet<missingObjNames> MissingObjects {get; set;}
     // contains fields uchar(16) BlobId;
 }
 public partial class runtimeDB: DbContext
 {
     public virtual DbSet<myObjects> myObjects {get; set;}
     // contains fields int InternalId, int blobType uchar() objectName, uchar() objectDesc.
     public virtual DbSet<idMap> IdMap {get; set}
    // contains fields int InternalId, uchar(16) BlobId
  }
```

so I've given up on the elegant solution and am now just trying to brute force it since I know that at most the list will contain 4k-10k entries (this is DB Cleannup code)

I've got the access to each db defined as

```
var runContext = new runtimeDBContextContainer();
var adminContext = new adminDBContextContainer();
```

then I go pull the list of blob names

```
var  MissingObjList = (adminContext.missingObjects.Select( ss =>  ss.BlobId )).ToList();

var listInternalIds = new List<int.();
foreach ( myBlobId in MissingObjList )
{
    int blobInternalId = (from r in context.IdMap
                               where r.BlobId == myBlobId
                               select r.InternalId).First(); 
    MissingObjList.Add(blobInternalId);
}
```

`So` far so good I end up with a list of internal ids to pull from the myObjects table

now I've got a

```
Public Class ObjectDataItem
{
    public int InternalId {get; set;}
    public int? blobType {get; set;}
    public string objectName {get; set;}
    public string ObjectDesc {get; set;}
}
```

So the code then goes on to try and build a list of missing objects (which the rest of the update code expects) by iterating through the list of InternalIds .  yes I know - this is dumb brute force code and its mainly because I'm a n00b at using Linq and 3 days of MSDN tutorials hasn't made me much smarter (i'm fixing inherited code)

```
var listBlobs = new List<ObjectDataItem>();

 foreach ( var missingBlobId in MissingObjList )
 {
    IQUERYABLE <myObjects> objQuery = (from o in runContext.myObjects
                                           where o.InteralId = missingBlobId
                                           select o);

     var thisObj = new {objQuery.InternalId, 
                        objQuery.blobType,
                        objQuery.objName,
                        objQuery.objDesc};

     listBlobs.Add(thisObj);
  }
```

These last two are causing me a syntax error.  essentially Intellisense tells me that my ObjQuery does not contain definitions of the ObjectDataItem I'm enumerating

and I'm too much of a N00b to figure out what I've done wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to create `thisObj` needs to be typed.  E.g.:

```
 var thisObj = new ObjectDataItem() {InternalID = objQuery.InternalId, 
                    blobType = objQuery.blobType,
                    objectName = objQuery.objName,
                    ObjectDesc = objQuery.objDesc};
```

As a side note, I'd recommend some consistency in naming things - even though this is a throw-away script. Public properties / fields are usually capitalized, whereas internal fields / local variables are lower-cased starts; having a field name `objName` in one place and `objectName` in another is also confusing.

Comment: Thanks, its inherited code.. trying to stay consistent with the context